# Dynamically Creating Textboxes MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I can dynamically create Textbox's in C# code which I have achieved, but people have been saying I need to follow the MVVM pattern, I looked into it and it seems really hard and I just can't get used to it.

I need to dynamically create text boxes, save the information in the text boxes to SQL and then be able to reopen it.

Here is a picture describing what I need to do:

[image]

**Is this possible to do without using the MVVM pattern?**

Just need abit of a push start and explanation of how I can do this, I don't want to be supplied with all the code.

EDIT1:

I don't know if this is right.

I have created a class called 'Standard' which looks like this:

```
namespace MVVModel
{
public class Standard
{

    string _title;
    string _question;



    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; }
    }

    public string Question
    {
        get { return _question; }
        set { _question = value; }
    }
}
}
```

Now I am going to create a ViewModel? What needs to be in this?

Comment: I'm a little understood why `TextBox` should be dynamically created? I understand the usual questionnaire, data which stored in the database.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev Because the user can add as many Titles and Questions as they want, they should not be limited, so I cannot just put the text boxes in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StandardCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Standard}">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Text={Binding Title} />
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text={Binding} />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Which is binded to any collection in your viewModel.

You can add as many items as required in the collection.

**Update:**

```
public class Standard
{
    string _title;
    ObservableCollection<string> _questions;        

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { 
            _title = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChanged(()=>Title);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Questions
    {
        get { return _questions; }
        set { 
            _questions = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChanged(()=>Questions);
        }
    }
}

public class StandardViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Standard> _standardCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<Standard> StandardCollection{
        get
        {
            return _standardCollection;            
        }
        set{
            _standardCollection = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChanged(()=>StandardCollection);
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at your Diagram 1: Its seems you may have multiple questions for each title. So here is the solution.

Yes, You will need the `Standard` class to make it simple.

Sorry, I don't have Visual Studio right now, I just wrote this code in NotePad, and pasted here. Not sure about errors. But just are high level idea.

Comment: So this would let me create as many text boxes as I want? If so .. How do I define the position for a Title or Question button click.

Comment: @user3157821 via Binding you need to define a object which contains all information you need for your TextBox and bind each Property

Comment: @WiiMaxx From my edited question, would that be done in the `Standard` class or the `ViewModel` class I'm about to create? + Do I need that standard class?

Comment: @TheIndianProgrammmer Thanks for your answer, I am going to review it now to make sure I can make sense of it all.