# Dynamically create TextBoxes and bind them to a list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to implement a create mask, on which a user can create a new technology with different versions (e.g: .NET with versions 4.5.2 and 4.6 etc.). For that I want the user to be able to dynamically add text boxes for additional versions.

A requirement for this is to use the MVVM Pattern, which i'm fairly new to. I created the following classes for this:

**Entitiy Classes (using Entity Framework)**

```
public class Tech : EntityBase
{
    // Properties
    public string TechName { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual ICollection<TechVersion> TechVersions{ get; set; }
}

public class TechVersion : EntityBase
{
    // Properties
    public string VersionNumber { get; set; }

    // Foreign Keys
    //public int TechId{ get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual Tech Tech{ get; set; }
}
```

**Technology View Model**

```
public class TechnologyUpdateViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private string _technologyName;
    public string TechnologyName
    {
        get
        {
            return _technologyName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_technologyName != value)
            {
                _technologyName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TechnologyName");
            }
        }
    }

    private ICommand _add;
    public ICommand Add
    {
        get
        {
            if (_add == null)
            {
                _add = new RelayCommand(e => CreateTechnology());
            }
            return _add;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_add != value)
            {
                _add = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Add");
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreateTechnology()
    {
        // Add new Technology from ViewModel Properties
    }
}
```

I am however having trouble with the XAML Code. Binding the Technology Name and adding a new Technology with just the name works fine (Textbox + Button).
But how do I get the dynamically created Textboxes and bind them to the ViewModel?

I've tried the approach I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948160/dynamically-creating-textboxes-mvvm)
For this I added `public ObservableCollection<string> Versions { get; set; }`
But most solutions try to create controls from an already filled list. I am trying to create text boxes and bind them to an empty list.

**TechnologyAdd.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Presentation.Views.TechnologyAddOrEdit"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Presentation.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel MaxWidth="250">
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock>Name: </TextBlock>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding TechnologyName}" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
        </DockPanel>

        <!-- Approach from the Link -->
        <ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Versions}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

        <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding Add}" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Maybe the whole MVVM thing confuses me too much but I can't seem to find a solution for this.
I would be happy about any information on how to approach this correctly.

Comment: Your `Add` Command should create an empty item in your collection which then gives you an additional item. Your `ViewModel` should have a `SelectedTechnology` Property to which you bind your newly created item.

Comment: I don't see where the datacontext is being set.  Without a datacontext nothing will bind.

Comment: the datacontext is being set via dependency injection in the background. as I stated the datacontext is connected correctly but I should have mentioned it sorry.
@XAMlMAX I didn't think about that! I will try it and give you feedback later today

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I tried @XAMIMAX approach but can't quite get it to work. I'll update my question with the way I tried it as soon as possible